# Syntax error in python. Error with an = sign

Tags: python, syntax

```
def InitialiseSudoku(): # this function is for initialisation of the sudoku function
                        cols = '0123456789ABCDEF'
                        rows = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'

global coordinates
coordinates = represent(rows, cols)

global subgridlist
subgridlist = ([represent(rows, c) for c in cols] + [represent(r, cols) for r in rows] + [represent(rs, cs) for rs in

    subgrids = dict((s, [u for u in subgridlist if s in u]) for s in coordinates)
    global constraintpartners
    constraintpartners = dict((s, set(sum(subgrids[s], [])) - set([s])) for s in coordinates)
    global dictionary
    global value
    i = 0
    for s in coordinates:
        dictionary[s] = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
        value[s] = input_list[i]
        prune_domain[s] = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
        i = i + 1
```

this produces a syntax error on the line:

```
subgrids = dict((s, [u for u in subgridlist if s in u]) for s in coordinates)
```

the specific error is the = sign

Comment: Your indentation is broken, and the line preceding `subgrids = ...` is incomplete, which is what triggers the syntax error.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is it just "syntax error" or is there more detail?

Comment: I suggest that you learn about function parameters and return values. These are often a better alternative to global variables.

Answer (score 0):

In general errors often are on the line before the error lists (this is because the line before is valid up to expecting a particular syntax construction.

This seems to be an instance of that case, on line 9 you state

```
for rs in
```

But that's not complete, it should be

```
for rs in <iterable/variable>
```

Where iterable/variableis whatever you are iterating over.